# List of Synchronous and Asynchronous Linux/Posix Signals

Tags: linux, signals, posix

I am interested to know the know the list of asynchronous SIGNALS and synchronous SIGNALS in Linux or Posix.

I find that the following SIGNALS are synchronous, is there any more to the list

```
SIGFPE
SIGSEGV
```

Thanks

Comment: Some information I got from glibc manual is as follows  [glibc reference](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_24.html)      Signals may be generated synchronously or asynchronously. A synchronous signal pertains to a specific action in the program, and is delivered (unless blocked) during that action. **Most errors generate signals synchronously**   Program Error Signals are   `SIGILL<br/>
SIGSEGV<br/>
SIGBUS<br/>
SIGABRT<br/>
SIGIOT<br/>
SIGTRAP<br/>
SIGEMT<br/>
SIGSYS<br/>`

Comment: Since you can send arbitrary signals to a process, all signals should be treated as asynchronous.