# Are POSIX signals resulting from a fault generated synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: multithreading, signals, posix

According to POSIX [definitions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html),

> 3.28 Asynchronously-Generated Signal
>
> A signal that is not attributable to a specific thread. Examples are signals sent via `kill()`, signals sent from the keyboard, and signals delivered to process groups. Being asynchronous is a property of how the signal was generated and not a property of the signal number. *All signals may be generated asynchronously*.

Then,

> 3.379 Synchronously-Generated Signal
>
> A signal that is attributable to a specific thread.
>
> For example, a thread executing an illegal instruction or touching invalid memory *causes* a synchronously-generated signal. Being synchronous is a property of how the signal was generated and not a property of the signal number.

If an illegal instruction *causes* a synchronously-generated signal, how *may* it be generated asynchronously?

For example, say I have a program that runs two threads, A and B. Now, suppose an illegal instruction takes place in A and causes a signal `SIGILL` to be raised. Is a POSIX-compliant system required to invoke the signal handler defined for `SIGILL` in thread A? Or is it *allowed* to interrupt
thread B and invoke that signal handler in B?

Related:

[List of Synchronous and Asynchronous Linux/Posix Signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392337/list-of-synchronous-and-asynchronous-linux-posix-signals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two scenarios are different, and 'synchronous' vs. 'asynchronous' is determined at the time of generation.

To rephrase your second question a bit, you ask, "can a synchronously-generated SIGILL attributed to a particular thread be delivered to a *different* thread in the same process?"

No.  A synchronously-generated signal can only be delivered to the thread that caused it. ([2.4.1 Signal Generation and Delivery](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_01))

Now as a caveat and as mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63602366/132382), normal signal masking semantics do not apply to some synchronously-generated signals.  In particular, as the [specs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) `pthread_sigmask` and `sigprocmask` say, *"[i]f any of the SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, or SIGBUS signals are generated while they are blocked, the result is **undefined**, unless the signal was generated [asynchronously]"*. (emphasis added)

Comment: So in order to catch signals such as SIGILL and have a well-defined program at the same time, one must the not block any such signal. Which in turn brings the possible scenario of a handler being invoked as a result of a user executing `kill -s SIGILL`. I've read about `SI_USER` that may help in such case, but I mean, what's the point of even allowing it? Unless the guys at POSIX thought a user could actually be the CPU and encounter an invalid instruction /s.

Comment: Normal practice is to capture & block sync signals (ill, bus, segv, ...).  In that way, you discriminate between real events (cannot be masked) and kill() - based signals (obey mask).   UNIX philosophy includes "If you stop someone from doing something stupid, you will stop someone from doing something more clever than you imagine."   It has a humility to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send SIGILL,SIGSEGV,SIGBUS,SIGFPE,... to processes via kill(2), or a specific thread via pthread_kill(3).  Masking only applies to kill generated signals, so if you install a handler for SIGILL, and mask it, your handler will only be invoked for *real* illegal instruction traps.